A causal signal is 0 for t<0
I read the defination of causal system i.e. the system whose output only depends on the present and past value of signal and not on the future. I want to know-

What is causal signal. Do causal system and signal implies same thing.
explain how a causal signal x(t) = 0, for t<0 and a non causal signal x(t) = 0, for t>0. Like what is the actual concept or analogy behind this.



What is causal signal.

A causal signal is zero for negative time/indexes, i.e. $x(t) = 0 \forall t < 0$

Do causal system and signal implies same thing.

No. Apples and oranges. Signals and Systems are different things and it's important to understand the difference. This being said you can state

The impulse response of a causal systems is a causal signal
If a causal signal is inputted into a causal system, the output will also be a causal signal


explain how a causal signal x(t) = 0, for t<0 and a non causal signal x(t) = 0, for t>0.

That's incorrect. The definitions are

Causal: $x(t) = 0 \forall t < 0$

Anti-causal: $x(t) = 0 \forall t > 0$

Non-causal: there are some non-zero values at both positive and negative times/indices



This needs to be on @PeterK's FAQ on meta.dsp.SE.
